# Awarding a bounty after the bounty grace period ends

Tags: support, reputation, bounty

I offered a bounty on a [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70760524/supplemental-string-resource-files-in-angular-i18n), but then had to be away for a few days at the end of the bounty grace period. Someone posted an acceptable answer, which I accepted and upvoted, but it was a few hours after the bounty grace period ended. Is the reputation really lost? I'd like it to be awarded to that answer. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Yes, the reputation is lost. The most you could do if you really want to award them with the rep is start another bounty to award an existing answer.

Comment: Well, that's disappointing.  I'll know for next time.  Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1):

This is addressed on the [main bounty FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) on Meta Stack Exchange (emphasis mine)—though you may have easily missed it given that the question it's filed under is the *opposite* of your question:

> #### What happens if I feel my question is still unanswered? / What is automatic awarding?
>
> [Approximately](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147576/bounty-not-awarded-after-the-end-of-the-grace-period/147577#147577) 24 hours after the end of the bounty period (once the grace period ends), if the bounty starter has not manually awarded the bounty, the bounty may be awarded automatically...
>
> …
>
> ***If no answer can be automatically awarded the bounty under any of the above two schemes, the bounty is not awarded to any answer, and is not refunded to the bounty starter.***

Or, [as @Nick wrote in the comments above](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415704/awarding-bounty-after-expiration#comment892523_415704):

> Yes, the reputation is lost. The most you could do if you really want to award them with the rep is start another bounty to award an existing answer.